# Sublime Text 3 in sudo not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to open sublimetext 3 with sudo mode it gives

```
Unable to find Sublime Text
```

I even renamed the folder to /Applications/Sublime Text3.app
as mentioned in [subline text forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15124)

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape the spaces (note the backslash characters) when launching from command-line:

```
sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Another tip: if you launch Sublime Text from command-line frequently, consider creating a symlink, e.g.:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

You can change the `subl` part to whatever you prefer, but it's pretty common to stick to that.

Comment: sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl 
Unable to find Sublime Text

Comment: Alright, this sounds like stupid advice, but is the name correct? You should probably use Tab-completion to rule out typos. Btw, does this really just happen when running Sublime Text with sudo rights?

Comment: Name is correct. If I remove sudo sublime text starts. Any way, Ignore this question I feel its designed that way may be to accidental overwriting of files. If i open a file that i don't have permission to write sublime open mac dialog for entering username password.

Comment: I've edited my answer since I just reinstalled OS X today. Turned out the target path was wrong.